# A question on Hartshorne Chapter III Proposition 2.6

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology

When I read Hartshorne, I saw the Proposition 2.6 in Chapter III as follows:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a ringed space. Then the derived functors of the functor $\Gamma(X,-)$ from the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules to the category of abelian groups coincide with the cohomology functors $H^{i}(X,-)$.

---

I am pretty confused here because I think it is just the definition of cohomology functor... Why should we bother to use the result about the flasque sheaf and acyclic resolution to prove this?

So I must miss something important and obvious. Please point it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functor $\Gamma(X,-)$ is initially defined on page 207 as a functor
$Sh(Ab, X) \to Ab$, where $Sh(Ab, X)$ is the category of sheaves of abelian groups on $X$.

You have the forgetful functor $U : Mod(O_X) \to Sh(Ab, X)$, and the claim is that
$$R^i(\Gamma(X,-) \circ U) \cong R^i(\Gamma(X,-)) \circ U,$$
which *does* need a proof.

Comment: thanks a lot! It answers my question perfectly!